# How to connect to network in Android using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I write codes like below to connect to network in Android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InitTask task = new InitTask();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.doInBackground(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
          protected String doInBackground(Void... p){

          // Do network thing...

          return str;
        }
    }
}
```

I used `AsyncTask` but `NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs.

Isn't it allowed to make AsyncTask as inner class in main activity? (I took an example in http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

What's the problem?

Comment: You are not using the AsyncTask properly. Just calling doInBackground will not create a Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used AsyncTask but NetworkOnMainThreadException occurs.

Because you are calling `doInBackground` method by creating `InitTask` class object.

To execute `doInBackground` method in other Thread call `task.execute()` method to start `AsyncTask` and use `onPostExecute` method to show Toast message when `doInBackground` method execution complete :

```
 @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               "Task Completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. When I call `task.execute()`, it occurs error. I  think it needs parameter. What parameter I should pass?

Comment: @user3858358: as in posted code you are passing first parameter as Void so `task.execute()` is fine. let me know what error occur?

Comment: `error: no suitable method found for makeText(Context,AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> cannot be converted to CharSequence)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> cannot be converted to int)`   I'm confused about "Void" and "void"

Comment: @user3858358: oh!, please remove Toast line from onCreate and put `task.execute()` in place of Toast  and move Toast inside `onPostExecute` as in my answer

Comment: @user3858358: Use only `InitTask task = new InitTask();task.execute()` in onCreate

Answer (score 1):

It is the call .doInBackground(), you have to execute Tasks via .execute(params);

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers are approximately correct but none are precise. The only line of code that you need to execute is this.
`new InitTask().execute();` 
Do this wherever and whenever you want to execute the background task.

Also have a look at the official android [guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). 

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Can you explain about `new InitTask().execute()`?. I have not seen this kind of constructor.

Comment: This means in English, " create a new instance of InitTask via its constructor and execute its methods (`doInBackground()` and other AsyncTask methods)". Now this happens because your InitTask class subclasses AsyncTask via the `extends` keyword. Hence the above statement for executing the background task.

Comment: Also please up vote my answer if my above comment helps!

Comment: Can I apply this method to other classes? Like `new MyClass().myMethod()`

Comment: That depends on the class you are calling.